Помогите реализовать код на stm32 для управления большим количеством светодиодов
Есть несколько рядов светодиодов, бп транзисторы npn и дешифратор. Мне нужно управлять этими рядами светодиодов, то есть включать и выключать ряды, когда надо. С stm32 подается сигнал на дешифратор а от него на бп транзисторы, транзисторы в свою очередь включают ряды светодиодов. Вместо одного светодиода на схеме их будет несколько цепочкой и таких рядов будет много, а на каждый ряд свой транзистор, следовательно получается много выходов, для этого беру дешифратор. Светодиоды будут работать по принципу динамической индикации. Значения вкл(1) или выкл(0) хранятся в двумерном массиве. Какой сигнал надо подавать на дешифратор, что бы зажечь опр ряд и как его формировать, если мне известно какие должны гореть, а какие нет(из двумерного массива). Я не прошу полностью писать код за меня, но дайте пожалуйста наводки как это сделать. 
